# Stream of Letters to Words

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

Given a string containing only letters (case-insensitive), split it into words of uniformly random lengths, using the distribution below, with the exception of the last word, which can be of any valid length (1-10). Your output is these words, as a space-separated string (`"test te tests"`), an array of strings (`["test","te","tests"]`), or any other similar output format.

### Word Length Distribution

```
Word Length - Fractional Chance / 72 - Rounded Percentage
1 - 2 / 72 - 2.78%
2 - 14 / 72 - 19.44%
3 - 16 / 72 - 22.22%
4 - 12 / 72 - 16.67%
5 - 8 / 72 - 11.11%
6 - 6 / 72 - 8.33%
7 - 5 / 72 - 6.94%
8 - 4 / 72 - 5.56%
9 - 3 / 72 - 4.17%
10 - 2 / 72 - 2.78%
```

Your odds do not need to match exactly - they can be off by `1/144`th, or `.69%`, in either direction (but obviously they still must sum up to `72/72` or `100%`).

Data roughly guessed from the fourth page, first figure of [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0019995858902298/1-s2.0-S0019995858902298-main.pdf?_tid=511ad80e-6cb2-11e7-ad2e-00000aacb360&acdnat=1500490058_0448c8a94d2bdaa5228521b4842e42b7).

## Test Cases with Sample Output

Behavior on very short (length < 11) test cases is undefined.

Note that I created these by hand, so they may or may not follow the uniform distribution above.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcd efgh i jklmnopq rs tu vwx yz

thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydog
t heq uick brown fo xj ump edo vert helazydog

ascuyoiuawerknbadhcviuahsiduferbfalskdjhvlkcjhaiusdyfajsefbksdbfkalsjcuyasjehflkjhfalksdblhsgdfasudyfekjfalksdjfhlkasefyuiaydskfjashdflkasdhfksd
asc uyoi uawer k nb a dhcviua hsid ufe r bfa lskd jhv lkcj haius dy faj se fbks dbfkals jcuyasjehf lkjh falk sd blhsgdf asudyfekjf alk sdjfhlk asefyu iaydskfja shdflk as dhf ksd
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13359/65836)

Comment: Can the last word be an empty string?

Comment: @rahnema1 you mean in an array output?

Comment: Yes, last element of the array output.

Comment: @rahnema1 sure, since if you join the array on space you'd just have a trailing space, which I would allow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“¤Œæ×¿®¬©¥¤‘Jẋ"$FẋLẊ‘1¦+\Ṭœṗ
```

A monadic link taking a list and returning a list of lists.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYy7CsIwGIWfRXFz8iUc1EdwSZufJpKLJH9Bt26CbjrUwbEWhOLeLkJKHyR9kZguh8O5fAcQ4hzCWLxcNdz7ui/dz31d4z7u7aqxeG58d5sv1lF3vrvGYOXq5d63zfDwbRn6yzYEZNxya7UEhBMiI8it0CoDE71CBloByxU1QFUuEzA2t0D51FgijwIMieMkR84IRU0onVhSG0gZMSTF@ECdQUSDgdkf)** (the footer separates the resulting list of lists with spaces)

#### How?

Uses all the percentages in the distribution rounded to their nearest integer (thus being within the 0.69% allowed thresholds).

```
“¤Œæ×¿®¬©¥¤‘Jẋ"$FẋLẊ‘1¦+\Ṭœṗ - Link: list (of characters), s
“¤Œæ×¿®¬©¥¤‘                 - code page indexes = [3,19,22,17,11,8,7,6,4,3]
               $             - last two links as a monad:
            J                -   range of length = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10]
              "              -   zip with:
             ẋ               -     repeat list = [[1,1,1],...,[9,9,9,9],[10,10,10]]
                F            - flatten (into one list of length 100)
                  L          - length of s
                 ẋ           - repeat list (one list of length 100*length(s) with the
                             -              correct distribution of integer lengths)
                   Ẋ         - shuffle
                      ¦      - sparse application of:
                    ‘        -   increment
                     1       -   to indexes: 1 (offset indexes for the partition below)
                        \    - cumulative reduce by:
                       +     -   addition (e.g. [4,4,7,1,...] -> [4,8,15,16,...])
                         Ṭ   - untruth (yield a list with 1s at those indexes (1 indexed)
                          œṗ - partition s at truthy indexes (note: excess ignored)
```

Comment: Your script may theoretically output the list whose first element is empty string. Not sure if it is allowed by the question.

Comment: @ThePirateBay yeah I actually just noticed this myself - I need to add 1 to the first element of my cumulative lengths; will update shortly to fix.

Comment: Fixed, and explanation added (can't ask to allow the leading space as the 1st word length would actually be using the wrong distribution).

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 94 bytes

```php
for(;$c=$argn[$k++];print$c." "[--$e])if(!$e)for($r=rand(0,71);$r>ord(x^"ywgSKAF:=?"[$e++]););
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/470507b43b89e2a98d4f14a2b1d474cdc7020370).

**breakdown**

```php
for(;$c=$argn[$i++];            # loop $c through string
    print$c                         # 2. print current character,
        ." "                        # 4. if remaining length is 0, print space
        [--$e]                      # 3. decrement remaining length
    )
    if(!$e)                         # 1. if remaining length is 0,
        for($r=rand(0,71);              # get random value from 0 to 71
            $r>ord(x^"ywgSKAF:=?"[$e++])    # and increment $e while $r is > probability
        ;);
```

Note: `ywgSKAF:=?` represents the increasing probabities -1: `[1,15,31,43,51,57,62,66,69,71]`

Comment: I wonder: Would the probabilities change if I´d call `rand()` for every comparison? If not, I could save 5 bytes.

Comment: They would certainly change, e.g. the probability of length 2 would be 70/72*16/72, which is higher than 14/72.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Something told me that would happen. Pity: That way I´d waste at least 5 bytes.

Comment: This is not the first time I've seen a supposedly complete PHP solution that didn't start with <? or <?php. Run as a standalone program, PHP needs that. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @manassehkatz You are missing `Run as pipe with -nR`. I.e. this code is supposed to be a parameter to php, not a file. Use `echo <input> | php -nR '<code>'` on the command line to execute.

Comment: @Titus Aha! I checked and the other 2 where I commented on this did NOT have `-nR` mentioned. I saw a rule that command line otpions should count as extra bytes, but you show the count as 94, which is the actual code length. Is there an exemption for this?

Comment: @manassehkatz https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/running-php-with-r-instead-of-code-tags Hmm seems I´d have to update a lot of byte counts. Will consider it for future posts.

Comment: The reality is that, unfortunately for those of us who love PHP, PHP rarely comes close to lowest on Code Golf. But I see the extra byte(s) for command line or compiler options included with other languages and "fair is fair". Arguably when a PHP entry is set up as a `function()` you could say that is the definition of a function (as opposed to a full program) and then the extra characters would not be needed, but most of the time a full program ends up shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 108 bytes

```matlab
@(s)mat2cell(s,1,[k=(w=repelems(1:10,[1:10;'AMOKGEDCBA'-63])(randi(72,1,n=nnz(s))))(cumsum(w)<=n) n-sum(k)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzNCoJAFEZfJdx4Lyg0BgXVQPZDi4geQFxM41TmzNUcf8qXn/RbHDiL85WyEZ1ybgcWjWgiqbQGG7AgKTj0vFaV0spYYGs2D5KJGz@@3i7n0/Gwj/1wuUgRakFZDqtozIgTDePXOJCtsa2BHreccEbhJAWm6ARZ8MRdZurxfOXvQhsqq09tm7brv7/BQ/cH)

*Takes the string as input and outputs an array of strings.

*The last element of the output may be an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <strike>154</strike> <strike>150</strike> <strike>147</strike> 145 bytes

Allright, this is my first attempt on code golf. Straight up with the code:

```python
import numpy.random as r
def f(s):
 i=0
 while i<len(s):
    i+=r.choice(11,p=[x/72. for x in [0,2,14,16,12,8,6,5,4,3,2]])
    s=s[:i]+' '+s[i:]
    i+=1
 return s
```

The second indent is by a tab char as you can see in my TIO version:
[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##HY5BboMwEADP8Sv2RhArGjtpWqHyEsSBgAnbgtddmwb6eYJynZFG49c4sDPbRpNnieDmya@5NK7jCZoAojrbQ38MaaGAypOCx0CjBfoarXvRA2Wl5O3A1Nqj1ujLann7MDn0LLAAOahOaFBfUF9RG/zEK77jBc9o6jpVh1CGqqA6SyDJQkVF/SpqBWLjLA7C5oVc3B@SONjfmdqfm/DD9bx877O24z8ruxmb/7Xje5JuTw).

What I do is adding a space in the string according to the given distribution. I veryfied my distribution by using:

```python
import collections
dist = r.choice(11,100000,p=[x/72. for x in [0,2,14,16,12,8,6,5,4,3,2]])
print collections.Counter(dist)
```

Which gave me:

```
Word Length - Rounded Percentage as asked - Rounded Percentage as counted
1 - 2.78% - 2.794%
2 - 19.44% - 19.055%
3 - 22.22% - 22.376%
4 - 16.67% - 16.638%
5 - 11.11% - 11.246%
6 - 8.33% - 8.362%
7 - 6.94% - 7.063%
8 - 5.56% - 5.533%
9 - 4.17% - 4.153%
10 - 2.78% - 2.780%
```

Which I think is correct enough. I then repeat that process of adding a space until the length of my string is succeeded. I also increment my position index by one after adding a space. I hope someone can help me golf this line out but I did not see how to get it out without falsifying the first space.

As I see my text I recognice that I have to learn alot about this Site. Could someone link me a guide how to use the Stackoverflow answer function in the comments so I can learn for my next posts.

---

Edit:

Apperently while rereading my post I did figure out a way to get rid of the i+=1. So i saved 4 bytes by doing that. The new code looks like this:

```python
import numpy.random as r
def f(s):
 i=-1
 while i<len(s):
  i+=r.choice(11,p=[x/72. for x in[0,2,14,16,12,8,6,5,4,3,2]])+1
  s=s[:i]+' '+s[i:]
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xcoMwEABr6xXXYYYLsRTbyTDhJQwFAWHOAZ1yEjH484RJu1vs@jUO7My20eRZIrh58msujet4giaAqM720B9DWiig8kUreAw0WqDP0bp/fKCslLwdmFp71Bp9WS2v7yaHngUWIFed0KA@o76iNviBV7zgGd/Q1HWaaXUIZagKqrMEkixUVNQKxMZZHITNC7m495M42J@Z2u8v4Yfrebnvo7bjXyu7GZvn2vEtSbc/)

---

Edit:

I figured out that i can remove some linebreaks.

```python
import numpy.random as r
def f(s):
 i=-1
 while i<len(s):i+=r.choice(11,p=[x/72. for x in[0,2,14,16,12,8,6,5,4,3,2]])+1;s=s[:i]+' '+s[i:]
 return s
```

---

Edit:
I modyfied my import and placed the definition of i inside the function.

```python
from numpy.random import*
def f(s,i=-1):
 while i<len(s):i+=choice(11,p=[x/72. for x in[0,2,14,16,12,8,6,5,4,3,2]])+1;s=s[:i]+' '+s[i:]
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY7BVoMwEADvfMXeANlWE2vbh/IlPA4IiaxCNt0EAX8eOc6bw4zf4sBO77sVnsDNk9/O0rr@AJo8S3xKemPBZgGpOqm8TGAZaDRAH6NxWchLKqpuYOpMphT6ql6fb/oMlgVWIFe/oEZ1QXVFpfGOV3zDC76ibpq8UO@hCnVJTZFCWoSayiYBMXEWB2H3Qi4e5TQO5jFT9/MpvDjL6/dxaXr@NXKYsf3bev5K8/0f)

Comment: Welcome on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Nice first post! I've edited your answer a bit to improve the formatting (title, syntax highlight), you can have a look at what changed to see the commands for your future posts. (I don't have any link to give you sadly, but hopefully someone else will)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and formatting my text. This helped me out and I did already use it in my Edit.

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 90 bytes

```
{k←⍵⋄{' '~⍨(2⊃⍵)↓k↑⍨⊃⍵}¨(↓(o[1;2]),0),↓o←1↓⍉2(1-⍨≢⍵)⍴+\((2 14 16 12 8,⌽1+⍳5)\⍳10)[72?⍨≢⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqbCDxqHfro@6WanUF9bpHvSs0jB51NQOFNB@1TQbKTgQKQQRqD63QAIpp5EcbWhvFauoYaOoAuflAAwyB9KPeTiMNQ12Q6s5FYO29W7RjNDSMFAxNFAzNFAyNFCx0HvXsNdR@1LvZVDMGSBoaaEabG9nDtcTWAh2loF6SkVpYmpmcnVSUX56Xll@RVZpbkJqSX5ZaBJTJSayqTMlPVwcA) Hit Run a few times to see how it changes.

**How?**

`72?⍨≢⍵` - roll 72 sided dice length of input times

`[...]` - index inside

`(2 14 16 12 8,⌽1+⍳5)\⍳10` - expand range of 10 by `2 14 16 12 8 6 5 4 3 2` (to create weighted random)

`+\` - cummulative sum

`⍉2(1-⍨≢⍵)⍴` - shape as a zipped table `x y z` → `z x, x y, y z`

`o←1↓` - drop first element

`(↓(o[1;2]),0),↓o` - encase with its first coordinate paired with 0

`¨` - for each pair (x, y)

`(2⊃⍵)↓k↑⍨⊃⍵` - take input from index x to y

`' '~⍨` - and remove spaces

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 155 bytes

```python
from random import*
def f(s):
 i=sum([[i+1]*[2,14,16,12,8,6,5,4,3,2][i]for i in range(10)],[])[randint(0,71)]
 return s if len(s)<11else s[:i]+' '+f(s[i:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY7BFoIgEEX3fsXsFJ1FUFnHU1/CYVEJOaVggJX9vOHqrd69d5xj56xYFuPdAP5i2zQ0jM7HMmu1AVME1mRA5zANhZRUcVVKgXyHvEYu8Ig17nGHWxRKkjLOAwHZFXXXBd8whVIxuZLJxmKDB85UBl7HyVsIQAZ6bZPkxLnug4YgG1JVDnmV1JIaxZbRp2sqyS/XW2q6d/R49oN148uHOL0/3/mXs@UP)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 164 bytes

```
(s=Length[c=Characters@#];t=0;l={};While[t<s,If[t+(r=RandomChoice[{2,14,16,12,8,6,5,4,3,2}->Range@10])<=s,l~AppendTo~r];t=Tr@l];""<>#&/@FoldPairList[TakeDrop,c,l])&
```

takes a string as input
outputs array of strings

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>43</s> 39 bytes

```
ＦθＦ⁺¹Ｉ‽⪫Ｅχ×Ｉκ⌕α§”v↷£o8″!”κω⊞υ⎇κω Ｆθ⁺ι⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3JCoMwFEX3/YqHq5eFUNeuxA7YIg3FH0iN1lRNNINDfz4VoWdzFofLLRumS8U672ulAUcCu2nnDEaQMmPxySRXPd6UkJizAaMjFKKvDO61JXARkiODxGaSVwsGaf64Z9fL@ZQG0JINmMku6kyDDopKS6ZXbGGGAAJC4sP/nGohLSacowCqBnTbLPaevUpe1e9GfNqul2oYtbFumpf168PJh6b7AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a trailing space if the last word was the exact size randomly chosen.

Comment: Yeah it does seem too long :/ Any idea for new features that would shorten it?

Comment: @ASCII-only I can't think of a good way of generating the probability table, which is already over 50% of the code. It would be nice if I didn't have to work around `Assign(Slice(q, i), q);` not working though.

Comment: That would work, just it's ambiguous, not entirely sure of the best way to fix that, sorry

Comment: Woah so much nesting

Comment: @ASCII-only Who cares if it saves bytes?

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 107 bytes

```perl
@B=((1,10,9,5,2)x2,(2,3,4)x12,(5,6)x6,7,(3,7,8)x4,9);while(10<length){$i=$B[rand 72];s/.{$i}//;print"$& "}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjRCoIwGEDhVxGR2OBXt5mamBDe9wTRhaXpyuaaK1fhq7e8OXwc2ag@tnZXFghRoAQyiIFhwwAxiGCNDV0YQ4JNAimgaMkGmzVkOJ863jeIkm3fiFZ3@OvxwisPqhK1k7JjPobBsuYwzKXiQrveynFna6vTuW4ubcevt/4uBvlQo36@JvP@/Aap@SBG6@/jgFBiffkH)

106 bytes of code +1 for -p

Comment: Welcome on the site! Nice to see a new Perl golfer, great answer! (you can still save a [few bytes](https://tio.run/##DcbdDoIgAIbhWyFzDbavFPzLra6kdWBFShERWlKtaydP3ue10ukizGd2kixtiNWWUg6eokYBwbwAFciQM8@nLVAyX6ICzaasmc9Rs51rzIlUYo8@WX1j9UsSWKfMEMULEo2d0pLwdKOlaYcuhOZwPMlz26nLVd/M3T5cPzxfo39//g) though). Also, I recommend adding some explanations, so non-Perl people have an idea of how you did it (and even for Perl coder, it saves a bit of time), but that's not mandatory and just up to you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 96+1 = 97 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag.

```ruby
i=0
m=[3,19,22,17,11,8,7,6,4,3].flat_map{|k|[i+=1]*k}
i=0
$_[i-1,0]=' 'while~/$/+1>i+=1+m.sample
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzNbsIwEITvPAUHJCRifgxVaQ/pi0QRWsferr0OibIYFJX20Zs66nFmvm@GZMZp8uVh0ZbVSel3dTwqfVZaqzd1Vq/qRZ3qHUa4XVrov578rHxR6nrD34vZWl0qv9XqUJfr5fpBPrqf/Wpf6I@ZKtqdQNtHN00gTRo7n@DhBr4asNTccyLxNqEbDEIUtoHukZtA4JPYESGIQ8NiDXLeQ74ACY4wcqBszEsk@bQIkjLvOPy3ASkyZHlMHkYrjAGELM6lJczEb9fffHeVadv/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>168</s> 152 bytes

```
<v?(0:i
~/<r
/x\/oo \
012\oo~\!/ !ox\
\v/:1=?^?\ooo>>
 x^
v\:1\/>> o
|/o\=\x^!/
voo/? >x
v\o~/ v_
>" "\?\x>xoo\
^oooooo<<< \
^.22/ \>x!/xv
^ooooooo_o<<<
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##7Y4xCsMwEAT7e8XJVaqc5dLIp48ccmfiaiEBcUXw1xU5kFfEC9PsFLvb/nq0lmq@jfNOh6QniZsAbDTGyYDDgnCAG1mVOS655N5CldgLVZujiSqD3gJbzEsQqoBkVu8ah3BdSQceLJurA0YF36SU@ky5T5OwqQfx@lNYT9va1v9dXFz8Jx8), or watch it at the [fish playground](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)!

Randomness is tricky in ><>: there's only one random instruction, `x`, which sets the fish's direction to either up, down, left or right. This is a complicated program, so here's a colour-coded diagram to help you:

[image: Colour-coded code!]

I tried to split up the probabilities into chunks so that the probabilities within and between the chunks were fairly simple (preferring, say, 1/3 to 25/72). I did this as follows:

[image: Tree of probabilities]

The fish starts at the grey bit of the code (**X**). This is fairly standard ><> code to read in all of the input. It gets more interesting, so let's move on.

Next, the fish comes to the light and dark green sections (**Y**). You may notice from the probability tree that the three major branches each sum to 1/3, and that each of these branches splits into a 2/3 sub-branch and a 1/3 sub-branch. The green sections of code cover these two levels of the tree. First, we pick a random number out of 0, 1, 2 with equal chance of each, in the top lobe of the light green bit. We can simulate a 1/3 chance using the four-way instruction `x` by cutting off one of the exits so that it just redirects the fish back to the `x` — then there are only three escape routes from the `x`, and by symmetry they have equal probabilities.

The next `x`, a little below this one, sends the fish to the `^` next to it with 2/3 chance — note that the fish wraps around if it swims left from the `x` — and down to a `\` with 1/3 chance. The fish then swims along one of the two tails of the light green section. These tails are functionally the same: each checks if we pushed 0, 1 or 2 earlier, and branches out accordingly. And this completes the first two levels of the tree.

The next six sections (**A**–**F**), in essence, use more `x`s to branch the fish further, and then use some number of `o`s to print a number of letters from the input. These sections range from straightforward (e.g. dark blue, **C**, which just prints three letters) to, well, not so straightforward (e.g. orange, **D**, which needs two `x`s to simulate a 3/8–5/8 split, printing letters in multiple stages). The details of these are left as an exercise. (I'm particularly pleased with yellow, **E**, which sends the fish in a loop-the-loop!)

After each of these branches, the fish ultimately reaches the pink section (**Z**). This draws all the branches back together, prints a space, then finally makes the fish jump to position (2,2) in the grid and start again at the first `x`.

---

In case the "it's complicated" explanation above doesn't convince you that this gives the correct probabilities, I also tested this on a length 65,000 input string (64 KiB, only 13 seconds in TIO!), and the resulting distribution of word lengths was

```
{{1,0.027377},{2,0.191237},{3,0.226599},{4,0.164128},{5,0.113064},{6,0.0818627},{7,0.0703885},{8,0.0543515},{9,0.0426089},{10,0.0283835}}
```

These probabilities are at most 0.0044 away from the expected probabilities.